# Div under input field

Tags: html, css

I want to display a div exactly below an input field. Of course, it's simple to achieve this, but I want this to work also with mobile. It's not working to good with media queries, so is there another way?

It's a live search. I want the div `#display` to be exactly under the input.

It's working on desktop machines, but not on mobile devices. Is there a general way or do I really have to use media queries with a fixed margin, width, and height?

```css
#display {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  position: absolute;
  width: 227px;
  border: solid;
  border-top: none;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
  border-width: thin;
  z-index: 1 !important;
}
    
.live-search {
  min-height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0" action="search.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
  <input type="search" name="search" required="" placeholder="Search">
  <button class="btn my-2 my-sm-0" id="search-btn" type="submit">Search</button>
</form>

<div id="display" style="display: block;">
  <a href="candidate.php?id=82925298">
    <div class="live-search">
      <li>82925298, Webdeveloper</li>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please post the relevant code snippets

Comment: @Alex Added more details.

Comment: What do you mean by not working on mobile device?

Answer (score 0):

```css
#display {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  width: 181px;
  border: solid;
  border-top: none;
  border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
  border-width: thin;
  z-index: 1 !important;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<form action="search.php" method="post" ...>
  <input type="search" name="search" ...>
  <button id="search-btn" type="submit">
          Search
  </button>
</form>

<div id="display">
  <a href="candidate.php?id=82925298">
    <div class="live-search">
      <li>82925298, WebDeveloper</li>
      <li>82925299, WebDesigner</li>
    </div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: You've nothing changed with the position!

Comment: He actually did